# jQuery: How to .show() an element with class that contains specific text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Update:
I have updated the question with the code I am using, for example based on (select) element if (option)paint(/option) selected I want to show or hide the whole "working class" div .working or if (option) Body Shop (/option) selected I want to show the whole "non-productive class" div .non-productive

I have multiple HTML elements with similar divs structure but different class names however some of these `divs` do share certain text, how can I use `.show()` to show those divs using their `.class` name which contains that certain shared text?

```
$('#qualifications').change(function(){
    if($('#qualifications').val() == 'Paint'){
        $('div:contains("Paint")').show();
        }
    })
});
```

this is bad example cause I want to target the element using `class name` instead of `('div:contains('Paint')')`

here's the code:

```
                <select id='qualifications'>
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option>Body Shop</option>
                    <option>Electrician</option>
                    <option>Mech</option>
                    <option>Paint</option>
                </select>

                    <!-- Working Class -->
                    <div class="working">
                        <div class="working-indicator">
                            <p>W</p>
                            <div class="user-circle">
                                <img src="imgs/usericon.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-info'>
                                <h6> Dennis Bokenkamp </h6>
                                <p><b><i>Paint</b></i></p>
                                <p>FIA</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-clocking'>
                                <img src="imgs/clockicon.png">
                                <p>10/8/2016</p>
                                <p>10:09:00 AM</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Non-Productive Class -->
                    <div class="non-productive">
                        <div class="non-productive-indicator">
                            <p>N</p>
                            <div class="user-circle">
                                <img src="imgs/usericon.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-info'>
                                <h6> Rick Richard </h6>
                                <p><b><i>Bodyshop 200%</b></i></p>
                                <p>DNF</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-clocking'>
                                <img src="imgs/clockicon.png">
                                <p>10/8/2016</p>
                                <p>11:09:00 AM</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: share html code please!

Comment: Use an each() loop to iterate through all of these divs, and if ($(this).text() === 'searchstring') then show()

Comment: So use the class in the selector? `div.YourClassName:contains("Paint")`

Comment: Could you show the HTML? The answers are interpreting your question differently, and it's not clear what you really mean. Is `Paint` in the text or the class?

Comment: ehsan, Barmar, I have updated the question with more description and the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#qualifications").on("change",function(){

        if($(this).val() == 'Paint') 

            $("div.working:contains(Paint)").show();

    })

})
```

I in below example use red border instead of `show` , because To show you what selected if you select paint of select box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
     <select id='qualifications'>
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option>Body Shop</option>
                    <option>Electrician</option>
                    <option>Mech</option>
                    <option>Paint</option>
    </select>

                    <!-- Working Class -->
                    <div class="working">
                        <div class="working-indicator">
                            <p>W</p>
                            <div class="user-circle">
                                <img src="imgs/usericon.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-info'>
                                <h6> Dennis Bokenkamp </h6>
                                <p><b><i>Paint</b></i></p>
                                <p>FIA</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-clocking'>
                                <img src="imgs/clockicon.png">
                                <p>10/8/2016</p>
                                <p>10:09:00 AM</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Non-Productive Class -->
                    <div class="non-productive">
                        <div class="non-productive-indicator">
                            <p>N</p>
                            <div class="user-circle">
                                <img src="imgs/usericon.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-info'>
                                <h6> Rick Richard </h6>
                                <p><b><i>Bodyshop 200%</b></i></p>
                                <p>DNF</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='user-clocking'>
                                <img src="imgs/clockicon.png">
                                <p>10/8/2016</p>
                                <p>11:09:00 AM</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#qualifications").on("change",function(){
        
        if($(this).val() == 'Paint') 
            
            $("div.working:contains(Paint)").css({border:"2px solid red"});
               
    })
    
})
       
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, I have question: I do have other divs with other class names but same structure as Working and non-productive divs that could possible also contain Paint, Bodyshop, Mech etc... how I do target all of them do i have to specify each class here?  $("div.classnames:contains(Paint)")

Comment: @alimarwan , you can save select value, `var value  = $(this).val();` and use `$("div.classNames:contains( " + value + ")").css({border:"2px solid red"});` if my post help you mark it please.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use this syntax: `$('div[class*="Paint"]').show()`

Comment: This is a very bad way to select a class when dot notation exists.

Comment: Do you think the :contains way is more preferable?

Comment: I think so yeah. Although if I have such a situation where I need to see if my class contains a word, I really feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I agree with you about the topic of this question, I also think there is an architectural problem. But the `[class=*]` is a native CSS selector therefore I think this is a good solution for this situation.